# Finding Uninitialized Member In Visual Studio 2010 Using Code Analysis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-analysis

I got some members in my class used without being initialized.  Unexpectedly, the MSVC++ 2010 compiler doesn't complain and code analysis produce no error/warning.  It does able to complain about uninitialized local var or unreference local var only.

What kind of setup should I do to pickup such errors?

Comment: Not quite on topic, but if you have an option to compile your code on Linux, you can use the excellent tool "valgrind" to detect when uninitialized memory is _used_ -- note that it is not always necessary to initialize variables, the only problem is if you read a variable before writing to it. GCC also warns you occasionally at compile time if it thinks you might use a variable uninitialized. Do you actually experience any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is not an error or warning. If class member does not initialized explicitly, it initializes with default initialization (if must be initialized).

records

```
class f{
std::string m
f():m(){};
};

class f{
std::string m
f(){};
};
```

doing the same.

If class member has no default constructor, it must be initialized in class constructor, and compiler wil give an error for this.

```
class A{
public:
   a(int i):m_i(i){};
protected:
  int m_i;
  a(){};
};

class B{
   A m_a;
   B(){}; 
};
```

This will cause compiler error.

Comment: Integers are not initialized to zero, but rather left undefined.

Comment: But is there any way that Visual Studio can catch this valid but just "bad coding style".

Comment: there are some tools for that. http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page for example... also studio has /analyze option in TeamSystem edition.

Comment: If you are willing to spend money, Rational Purify would be able to detect this error (at runtime).